# Instagram Privacy policy URL

Tags: instagram-api

It's not a programming question, but I can't find other place to ask it: instagram doesn't have a support and there is no instagram developer forum.

I am developing an application that doesn't require any permissions except access to public data, it doesn't have login functionality. Do I still need to create a privacy policy and provide a link to it in client properties? If so, what should I write in it assuming I don't have access to user data?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Instagram Platform Policy](https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/) (Item 8), you should have a privacy policy.

> Provide a publicly accessible privacy policy that tells people what you collect and how you will use this information.

If you don't access user data, state that in your policy.